Help with making a table
I'm trying to replicate the following table:

At first I was thinking of making it by dividing all the content into single cells, but since there are those numbers enclosed in curly brackets, I told myself it was not very convenient (especially considering the numbers on the left of each curly bracket are actually vertically aligned). Then I thought of dividing the table into "groups" of cells
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{II}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{III}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{IV}} \\ \cline{1-1}
n \qquad l \qquad m & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{1} & \multirow{14}{*}{} & 1 orbitale & 1 \\ \cline{3-4} 
 &  & 1 orbitale & \multirow{4}{*}{4} \\
 &  & \multirow{3}{*}{3 orbitali} &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} 
\multirow{9}{*}{3} &  & 1 orbitale & \multirow{9}{*}{9} \\
 &  & \multirow{3}{*}{3 orbitali} &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  & \multirow{5}{*}{5 orbitali} &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

(which results in:)

, artificially make the n, l, m columns with \qquad and then handle the aligned stuff using the align environment. However, pdfTeX immediately throws out an error saying I can't use it inside a tabular environment.
Any idea on how to proceed?
Thanks

You need math mode for $\qquad$ . // How would you present this information if you don't have curly brackets available? Do they even convey any useful information or do they just introduce visual noise? can't you do it more to-the-point, perhaps with fewer rows? // Have a look at package booktabs , which helps you create more professionally looking tables. https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

@MS-SPO Well, those brackets actually tell me a lot on the subject given, so I guess I can't just get rid of them. There's a relation between the l and m column and I think that's important to show. Still, I'll take a look at the booktabs package, but I need those brackets I'm afraid.

I usually would add the curly brackets using tikzmark, but if you want the calligraphic effect, you'd need to use the package/library for calligraphy or another method.

I would suggest to use tabularray to make table data cleaner. As for the braces, I don't know a way to make TeX to adjust their height inside the table, so I've done that separately. The macros \briii and \brv output breaces 3 and 5 rows tall. Then I just put them into the appropriate cells.
The code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\newcommand{\briii}{\mbox{$\left\{\vphantom{\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c},
  row{1}={abovesep=0pt},
  row{Z}={belowsep=0pt}
}
0\\0\\0
\end{tblr}}\right.$}}
\newcommand{\brv}{\mbox{$\left\{\vphantom{\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={c},
  row{1}={abovesep=0pt},
  row{Z}={belowsep=0pt}
}
0\\0\\0\\0\\0
\end{tblr}}\right.$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={cccclcc},
    cell{1}{1}={c=4}{c},
    cell{1}{5-7}={r=2}{c},
    vline{1,5-8}={},
    hline{1,3,Z}={},
    hline{2}={1-4}{},
    hline{4,8}={dashed},
    row{2-Z}={mode=math},
    column{6}={mode=text},
    cell{5,9}{3}={r=3}{c},
    cell{12}{3}={r=5}{c},
    column{2}={leftsep+=0.6em},
    column{3}={colsep=0pt},
    column{4}={leftsep=0pt},
}
I &   &        &    & II          & III                    & IV \\
n & l &        & m  &             &                        & \\
1 & 0 &        & 0  & \psi_{100}  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{1s}$ & 1 \\
2 & 0 &        & 0  & \psi_{200}  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{2s}$ & 4 \\
  &   & \briii & -1 & \psi_{21-1} &                        &   \\
  & 1 &        &  0 & \psi_{210}  & 3 orbitali $\psi_{2p}$ &   \\
  &   &        & +1 & \psi_{211}  &                        &   \\
3 & 0 &        & 0  & \psi_{300}  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{3t}$ & 9 \\
  &   & \briii & -1 & \psi_{31-1} &                        &   \\
  & 1 &        &  0 & \psi_{310}  & 3 orbitali $\psi_{3p}$ &   \\
  &   &        & +1 & \psi_{311}  &                        &   \\
  &   & \brv   & -1 & \psi_{32-1} &                        &   \\
  &   &        & -2 & \psi_{32-2} &                        &   \\
  & 2 &        &  0 & \psi_{320}  & 5 orbitali $\psi_{3d}$ &   \\
  &   &        & +1 & \psi_{321}  &                        &   \\
  &   &        & +2 & \psi_{322}  &                        &   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}

The output:


We have a winner! Thank you so much

A solution with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|ccc|l|c|c|}
\Hline
\Block{1-3}{I} &   &    & \Block[c]{2-1}{II} & \Block{2-1}{III} & \Block{2-1}{IV} \\
\Hline
$n$ & $l$ & $m$  \\
\Hline
$1$ & $0$ & $0$  & $\psi_{100}$  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{1s}$ & $1$ \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
$2$ & $0$ & $0$  & $\psi_{200}$  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{2s}$ & $4$ \\
    &     & $-1$ & $\psi_{21-1}$ \\
    & $1$ & $0$  & $\psi_{210}$  & 3 orbitali $\psi_{2p}$ \\
    &     & $+1$ & $\psi_{211}$  \\
\Hline[tikz=dashed]
$3$ & $0$ & $0$  & $\psi_{300}$  & 1 orbitale $\psi_{3t}$ & $9$ \\
    &     & $-1$ & $\psi_{31-1}$ \\
    & $1$ & $0$  & $\psi_{310}$  & 3 orbitali $\psi_{3p}$ \\
    &     & $+1$ & $\psi_{311}$  \\
    &     & $-1$ & $\psi_{32-1}$ \\
    &     & $-2$ & $\psi_{32-2}$ \\
    & $2$ & $0$  & $\psi_{320}$  & 5 orbitali $\psi_{3d}$ \\
    &     & $+1$ & $\psi_{321}$  \\
    &     & $+2$ & $\psi_{322}$  \\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix{\{}{5-3}{7-3}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{9-3}{11-3}{.}
  \SubMatrix{\{}{12-3}{16-3}{.}{}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}


